# Most efficient way to insert Rows into MySQL Database

Tags: c#, mysql, performance

I've read a lot of questions about that but i couldn't find one that is fast enough. I think there are better ways to insert a lot of rows into a MySQL Database

I use the following code to insert 100k into my MySQL-Database:

```
public static void CSVToMySQL()
{
    string ConnectionString = "server=192.168.1xxx";
    string Command = "INSERT INTO User (FirstName, LastName ) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName);";
    using (MySqlConnection mConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        mConnection.Open();

        for(int i =0;i< 100000;i++) //inserting 100k items
        using (MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand(Command, mConnection))
        {
            myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", "test");
            myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", "test");
            myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

This takes for 100k rows about 40 seconds. How can i make this faster or a little more efficient?

Might be faster to insert multiple rows via a DataTable/DataAdapter or at once:

```
INSERT INTO User (Fn, Ln) VALUES (@Fn1, @Ln1), (@Fn2, @Ln2)...
```

Due to security issues i can't load the data into a file and MySQLBulkLoad it.

Comment: Fubo is on the right track, but it needs to be `parameterized`. Then you can fiddle with batch sizes to get the best performance. These batch sizes will differ according to CPU/RAM etc

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Here is my "multiple inserts"-code.

The insertion of 100k rows took instead of 40 seconds only **3 seconds**!!

```
public static void BulkToMySQL()
{
    string ConnectionString = "server=192.168.1xxx";
    StringBuilder sCommand = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO User (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ");           
    using (MySqlConnection mConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        List<string> Rows = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            Rows.Add(string.Format("('{0}','{1}')", MySqlHelper.EscapeString("test"), MySqlHelper.EscapeString("test")));
        }
        sCommand.Append(string.Join(",", Rows));
        sCommand.Append(";");
        mConnection.Open();
        using (MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand(sCommand.ToString(), mConnection))
        {
            myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

The created SQL-statement looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO User (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('test','test'),('test','test'),... ;
```

**Update**: Thanks *Salman A* I added `MySQLHelper.EscapeString` to avoid code injection which is internally used when you use parameters.

Comment: Just do a replace on apostrophes in "test" with a double apostrophe, and you'll be fine. "test" ==>  "test".Replace("'", "''")

Comment: @fubo Should be. I am guessing it uses same or similar code that escapes parameter values.

Comment: It just works  btw, instead of string.Format, I find it easier to use $"'{MySqlHelper.EscapeString("test")}'"

Comment: Now you create a pretty long string in memory.

Comment: can we use a stored procedure with this?

Comment: @user1431072 see my latest comment about `MySQLHelper.EscapeString`, which is valid because it's the same technique as parameters - but you can also use parameters and count them up `for(..){ cmd.Parameters.Add("@myParameter" + i, myValue };`

Comment: Efficient, but if you need the Inserted item's ID this may not work.

Comment: I thought this code can be subjected to SQL Injection? Can it be?

Comment: @Akshay no - read the last sentence of the answer

Answer (score 19):

I did a small test using three things MySqlDataAdapter,transactions and UpdateBatchSize. It is about 30 times faster than your first example. Mysql is running on separate box so there is latency involved. The batchsize might need some tuning. Code follows:

```
string ConnectionString = "server=xxx;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx;Database=xxx";

string Command = "INSERT INTO User2 (FirstName, LastName ) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName);";


 using (var mConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
     {
         mConnection.Open();
         MySqlTransaction transaction = mConnection.BeginTransaction();

        //Obtain a dataset, obviously a "select *" is not the best way...
        var mySqlDataAdapterSelect = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from User2", mConnection);

        var ds = new DataSet();

        mySqlDataAdapterSelect.Fill(ds, "User2");


        var mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

        mySqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand(Command, mConnection);


        mySqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 32, "FirstName");
        mySqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@LastName", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 32, "LastName");
        mySqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;

        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = ds.Tables["User2"].NewRow();
            row["FirstName"] = "1234";
            row["LastName"] = "1234";
            ds.Tables["User2"].Rows.Add(row);
        }

         mySqlDataAdapter.UpdateBatchSize = 100;
         mySqlDataAdapter.Update(ds, "User2");

         transaction.Commit();

         stopwatch.Stop();
         Debug.WriteLine(" inserts took " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
    }
}
```

Comment: Took only 13 seconds - depending on UpdateBatchSize. And the MySqlTransaction seems to be required.

Comment: Ok so you only got 3 times faster, to bad

Comment: you can use `mySqlDataAdapterSelect.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Mapped);` to get a empty structure from the database

Comment: Ok nice. I just did this sample for you, I was curious if it was doable or not. I always use NHibernate or similar :)

Comment: To make this method more generic it's possible to `myAdapter.InsertCommand= new MySqlCommandBuilder(myAdapter).GetInsertCommand()`

Comment: you did it man ... I just insert 10000 records in 25 seconds. This is super duper fast

Comment: This is easily the most performant one, observable when the MySQL server is located far away.

Comment: You can also use `mySqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommandBuilder(mySqlDataAdapterSelect).GetInsertCommand();`

Answer (score 13):

Execute command in a `Transaction` and reuse same instance of command for each iteration. For further performance optimization, send 100 queries in one command. Going for parallel execution could give better performance (`Parallel.For`) but make sure each parallel loop get its own `MySqlCommand` instance.

```
public static void CSVToMySQL()
{
    string ConnectionString = "server=192.168.1xxx";
    string Command = "INSERT INTO User (FirstName, LastName ) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName);";
    using (MySqlConnection mConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)) 
    {
        mConnection.Open();
        using (MySqlTransaction trans = mConnection.BeginTransaction()) 
        {
            using (MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand(Command, mConnection, trans)) 
            {
                myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                for (int i = 0; i <= 99999; i++) 
                {
                    //inserting 100k items
                    myCmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", "test");
                    myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", "test");
                    myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                trans.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. that took 44 seconds :( seems that the `MySqlTransaction ` is handled by the SQL-Server and each row is sent seperately

Comment: Just pointing out, that this method is Blocking, and changing the method to async and `ExecuteNonQuery` to `ExecuteNonQueryAsync`, and `Open` to `OpenAsync` will not prevent blocking.

Comment: The method in the answer which got the 100 points bounty is far more performant than this method.

Answer (score 6):

This way may not be faster than the stringbuilder approach, but it is parameterized:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Bulk insert some data, uses parameters
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="table">The Table Name</param>
    /// <param name="inserts">Holds list of data to insert</param>
    /// <param name="batchSize">executes the insert after batch lines</param>
    /// <param name="progress">Progress reporting</param>
    public void BulkInsert(string table, MySQLBulkInsertData inserts, int batchSize = 100, IProgress<double> progress = null)
    {
        if (inserts.Count <= 0) throw new ArgumentException("Nothing to Insert");

        string insertcmd = string.Format("INSERT INTO `{0}` ({1}) VALUES ", table,
                                         inserts.Fields.Select(p => p.FieldName).ToCSV());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        using (MySqlCommand sqlExecCommand = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            conn.Open();
            sb.AppendLine(insertcmd);
            for (int i = 0; i < inserts.Count; i++)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(ToParameterCSV(inserts.Fields, i));
                for (int j = 0; j < inserts[i].Count(); j++)
                {
                    sqlExecCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("{0}{1}",inserts.Fields[j].FieldName,i), inserts[i][j]);
                }
                //commit if we are on the batch sizeor the last item
                if (i > 0 && (i%batchSize == 0 || i == inserts.Count - 1))
                {
                    sb.Append(";");
                    sqlExecCommand.CommandText = sb.ToString();
                    sqlExecCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    //reset the stringBuilder
                    sb.Clear();
                    sb.AppendLine(insertcmd);
                    if (progress != null)
                    {
                        progress.Report((double)i/inserts.Count);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(",");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This uses the helper classes as below:

```
/// <summary>
/// Helper class to builk insert data into a table
/// </summary>
public struct MySQLFieldDefinition
{
    public MySQLFieldDefinition(string field, MySqlDbType type) : this()
    {
        FieldName = field;
        ParameterType = type;
    }

    public string FieldName { get; private set; }
    public MySqlDbType ParameterType { get; private set; }
}

///
///You need to ensure the fieldnames are in the same order as the object[] array
///
public class MySQLBulkInsertData : List<object[]>
{
    public MySQLBulkInsertData(params MySQLFieldDefinition[] fieldnames)
    {
        Fields = fieldnames;
    }

    public MySQLFieldDefinition[] Fields { get; private set; }
}
```

And this helper method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Return a CSV string of the values in the list
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
    private string ToParameterCSV(IEnumerable<MySQLFieldDefinition> p, int row)
    {
        string csv = p.Aggregate(string.Empty,
            (current, i) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(current)
                    ? string.Format("@{0}{1}",i.FieldName, row)
                    : string.Format("{0},@{2}{1}", current, row, i.FieldName));
        return string.Format("({0})", csv);
    }
```

Maybe not super elegant but it works well. I require Progress tracking so that is included for me, feel free to remove that part.

This will produce SQL commands similar to your desired output.

EDIT: ToCSV:

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Return a CSV string of the values in the list
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="intValues"></param>
    /// <param name="separator"></param>
    /// <param name="encloser"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
    public static string ToCSV<T>(this IEnumerable<T> intValues, string separator = ",", string encloser = "")
    {
        string result = String.Empty;
        foreach (T value in intValues)
        {
            result = String.IsNullOrEmpty(result)
                ? string.Format("{1}{0}{1}", value, encloser)
                : String.Format("{0}{1}{3}{2}{3}", result, separator, value, encloser);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: the extension `ToCSV` is missing

Answer (score 6):

If `Add` of `AddWithValue` does not escape strings, you must do such in advance to avoid SQL injection and syntax errors.

Build `INSERT` statements with only 1000 rows at a time.  That should run easily 10 times as fast as what you started with (1 row per `INSERT`).  Doing all 100K at once is risky and possibly slower.  Risky because you might blow out some limit (packet size, etc); slower because of the need for a huge `ROLLBACK` log.  `COMMIT` after each batch, or use `autocommit=1`.

Comment: To add, build insert statements with only `max_allowed_packet` bytes or less. This is the limit that is most likely to blow with large queries.

Comment: a statement with string concartenation or parameters? can you show me a sample?

Answer (score 5):

One way to accelerate would be wrapping all inserts into ONE transaction (SQL-Server code):

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Sql.ConnectionString")))
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();

    try 
    {  
        foreach (string commandString in dbOperations)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandString, conn, transaction);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        transaction.Commit(); 
    } // Here the execution is committed to the DB
    catch (Exception)
    {
      transaction.Rollback();
      throw;
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

Another way is to load the CSV-File into a datatable, and use the batching feature of DataAdapter

```
 DataTable dtInsertRows = GetDataTable(); 

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_BatchInsert", connection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;

    // Set the Parameter with appropriate Source Column Name
    command.Parameters.Add("@PersonId", SqlDbType.Int, 4, dtInsertRows.Columns[0].ColumnName);   
    command.Parameters.Add("@PersonName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, dtInsertRows.Columns[1].ColumnName);

    SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adpt.InsertCommand = command;
    // Specify the number of records to be Inserted/Updated in one go. Default is 1.
    adpt.UpdateBatchSize = 2;

    connection.Open();
    int recordsInserted = adpt.Update(dtInsertRows);   
    connection.Close();
```

You find a nice example [here](http://jishnutkl.wordpress.com/tag/mysql-bulk-insert-from-c-net/).

Or you can use the MySQL [BulkLoader](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-bulk-loader.html) C# class:

```
var bl = new MySqlBulkLoader(connection);
bl.TableName = "mytable";
bl.FieldTerminator = ",";
bl.LineTerminator = "\r\n";
bl.FileName = "myfileformytable.csv";
bl.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1;
var inserted = bl.Load();
Debug.Print(inserted + " rows inserted.");
```

If you do multiple inserts in one command, you might still squeeze an inch or two out by using StringBuilder instead of string.

Comment: the trancaction code took 50 seconds in this case instead of 40 seconds before :(

Comment: @fubo: Looks like MySQL behaves differently from SQL-Server then.

Comment: Beware of Isolation Level. You can slow down your database and cause deadlocks

Comment: Just for help, MySqlBulkLoader gives error if there is any space in column name. So first remove space in column names from CSV.

Answer (score 4):

As Stefan Steiger says, [Bulk Insert](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html) is suitable for your situations.

Another trick is using staging tables, so instead of writing directly to the production table, you will write to staging one (which has the same structure).
Having written all info you just swap tables.
With staging aproach you will avoid locking tables for insertion (can be used for update and delete too), and this pattern is heavily used with MySQL in some projects.

Also, disabling table keys may speed up insertion, but also can introduce some problems when you enable them (only for MyISAM engine).

**Added**:

Let's say you have table `Products`:

- *ProductId*
- *ProductName*
- *ProductPrice*

For staging purpose you create a staging table called `ProductsStaging`, with the same set of columns.

All your operation you do on staging table:

```
UpdateStagingTable();
SwapTables();
UpdateStagingTable();
```

because after swap your staging table does not have the new data, you invoke the same method once again.
In `SwapTables()` method you execute one SQL statement:

```
RENAME TABLE Products TO ProductsTemp,
             ProductsStaging TO Products,
             ProductsTemp TO ProductsStagin;
```

The speed of data manipulations depends on the MySql engine (e.g. InnoDB, MyISAM etc.), so you can also speed up inserts by changing engine.

Comment: You can make the `RENAMEs` atomic by using a single statement.  That way, `Products` is always available.

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled upon a similar problem while working with EF - MySQL. The EF inserts were way too slow and hence used the approach mentioned by [fubo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1315444/fubo). To start with, the performance improved drastically (~20K records were inserted in ~10 seconds) but degraded as the table grew in size, with ~1M records in the table, the insertion took ~250 seconds.

Finally figured out the issue! The PK of the table was of type GUID (UUID -
 char(36)). As UUIDs cannot index sequentially and every insert required the indexes to be rebuilt, it slowed down.

The fix was to replace the PK with bigint (or int) and set it as an identity column. This improved the performance, the insertions took an average of ~12 seconds with ~2M+ records in the table!

Thought I'd share this finding here just in case someone gets stuck on a similar problem!

Answer (score 2):

I have found the way to avoid using a file for the bulk insert. In [this connector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector) was implementer load from stream.
So loading could be done something like that

```
  public void InsertData(string table, List<string> columns, List<List<object>> data) {

  using (var con = OpenConnection() as MySqlConnection) {
    var bulk = new MySqlBulkLoader(con);
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
      bulk.SourceStream = stream;
      bulk.TableName = table;
      bulk.FieldTerminator = ";";
      var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

      foreach (var d in data)
        writer.WriteLine(string.Join(";", d));

      writer.Flush();
      stream.Position = 0;
      bulk.Load();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Just remember to set the columns as well.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is an idea, not example or solution. What if you don't use INSERTs but pass data as multiple parameters (not necessary all 100K at once, you can use bundles of 1K for example) to STORED PROCEDURE which itself doing INSERTs.

Answer (score 0):

A bulk operation would be a good manner to lead with that. Something that read your properties and then create a bulk query for you...

There's a github repository that contains both useful methods: BulkInsert and BulkUpdate using MySql and EF6+.

The BulkUpdate/BulkInsert basically read all properties from your generic entity and then create the bulkquery for you.

Ps: This has been intended developed to my needs and the project is opened to who concerns to improve it or change it for a better solution that will worth to the community.

Ps²: If it doesnt fulfill the trouble, try to make changes on the project to improve and achieve what you want, it's a good start at least.

Please, take a look at [here](https://github.com/brunocanmaster/BulkInsert-And-BulkUpdate-MySql-EF6-)