# MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery with Transaction still sends data to server before Commit is called

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, transactions, mysql-connector

I am inserting a large amount of data. I think it is a good idea to wrap multiple INSERT statement into "batches", so I used Transaction to send to the server once every thousands INSERT statement:

```
        using (var reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var rowCount = 0;

            using (var transaction = mySqlConnection.BeginTransaction())
            {
                // Build the params used for insert queries
                var paramCount = reader.FieldCount;
                var queryParamBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                for (int paramNo = 0; paramNo < paramCount; paramNo++)
                {
                    queryParamBuilder.Append($"@p{paramNo},");
                }

                // Remove final comma ,
                queryParamBuilder.Remove(queryParamBuilder.Length - 1, 1);
                var queryParam = queryParamBuilder.ToString();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    using (var insertCommand = new MySqlCommand($"INSERT INTO {table.Name} VALUES({queryParam})", mySqlConnection))
                    {
                        insertCommand.Transaction = transaction;

                        for (int i = 0; i < paramCount; i++)
                        {
                            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@p{i}", reader[i]);
                        }

                        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    rowCount++;
                }

                transaction.Commit();
            }
```

I thought Transaction would help, but no, I realize data are being sent to the server every time `insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` is called (although, correctly, the data is not there yet until Commit() is called). The reason is because, if there is a PRIMARY KEY or FOREIGN KEY error there, an exception is immediately thrown at the `ExecuteNonQuery()` call, not `Commit()` call.

Is there a way to send data to server only once? Will `TransactionScope` work for this case?

Comment: First I recommend you to put `while (reader.Read())` inside `using (var insertCommand`

Comment: A transaction does not prevent sending data. It's allow you to discard previous command. The transaction mechanism is sever side. The client just say to the server *begin the transaction now* and *stop the transaction now*. All other operation is same as without transaction.

Comment: @McNets My intention is to use multiple INSERT statements, but not 1 statement with multiple INSERT (because of the unknown parameters)

Comment: You can reuse the same insert statement without generate a new one for every param value. It does not affect the transaction.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know they are reusable. Will try later. I am trying the adapter as suggested by Kalten.

Comment: @McNets Can't reuse them, receive error "Parameter '@p0' has already been defined".

Comment: @Kalten `MySqlBulkLoader` seems to support CSV or similar file only? My table is around 5GB, is there a way without creating CSV file?

Comment: I also tried the Adapter. I don't know if it's my side, but the Update/Commit commands take around 12 seconds for 1000 rows, which is not really good for my need. Is there any faster way?

Comment: Usually I generate an instance of my SqlCommands in class constructor, (not in a using statement), and .Add all the needed parameters without values. I suppose you get the error due `insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@p{i}", reader[i]);`

Comment: You can try to merge many insert statements into one command. The [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html) says you can enable/disable some constraint checking. That could help.

Comment: @Kalten Your deleted link, it works like a charm. Using the CSV script + BulkLoader. 10k rows in under a second! Please mark this post as duplicate :)

Comment: I put it back [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25323560/most-efficient-way-to-insert-rows-into-mysql-database). See answer with bounty too.