# How properly insert data from dynamic DataTable to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, datatable

Actually i have a method where the user is able to choose data from excel file and choose between some headers name which are set statically and are equals to MySQL columns name in a table, then i just collect that data in a DataTable.

Now i would be able to store that data in MySQL database but which would be the best method to insert that data from a DataTable into MySQL? The rows of DataTable could contain more than 50.000/100.000 items.

That's how the DataTable could look's like (The header is choosen dynamically by the user from a combobox)
[image]

So in this Insert method which would be the best way to add that data? Should i just loop throw dataTable items and make multiple inserts?

```
Private Sub InsertDB()
    Dim dataTable = ExcelToDT(TxtUpload.Text, ColumnHeader(PanelColumns, Column))
    Dim dbCon As New Odbc.OdbcConnection
    Dim conStr As String = "DSN=WRRPT"
    dbCon.ConnectionString = conStr
    dbCon.Open()




    Dim cmd As New Odbc.OdbcCommand
    With cmd
        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO ? VALUES ?"
        .Connection = dbCon
    End With

    Dim reader As Odbc.OdbcDataReader
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader

    dbCon.Close()
    reader = Nothing
    cmd = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Look into using data adapters, both to retrieve the data and save it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most efficient way to insert Rows into MySQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25323560/most-efficient-way-to-insert-rows-into-mysql-database)