# MySqlConnector C# INSERT large number of rows

Tags: c#, mysql

I have data, about 200,000 rows that need to be written to the database. I wrote this code, but it takes too long to write to the database. Is it possible to insert multiple `Values` in one request `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` via Parameters? Or some other way?

```
string sqlcommand = "INSERT INTO `Mail` ( `threadID`, `mailID`, `UserID`, `UserName`, `mailTime`, `body`) values (@threadID, @mailID, @UserID, @UserName, @mailTime, @body)";
                using (MySqlConnection mySqlConnection2 = new MySqlConnection(sqlconnect))
                {
                    mySqlConnection2.Open();
                    MySqlCommand cmd = mySqlConnection2.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = sqlcommand;

                    MySqlParameter threadID = new MySqlParameter("@threadID", MySqlDbType.Int32);
                    MySqlParameter mailID = new MySqlParameter("@mailID", MySqlDbType.Int32);
                    MySqlParameter UserID = new MySqlParameter("@UserID", MySqlDbType.Int32);
                    MySqlParameter UserName = new MySqlParameter("@UserName", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                    MySqlParameter mailTime = new MySqlParameter("@mailTime", MySqlDbType.DateTime);
                    MySqlParameter body = new MySqlParameter("@body", MySqlDbType.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(threadID);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(mailID);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(UserID);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(UserName);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(mailTime);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(body);

                    foreach (Mail_Data data in List)
                    {
                        threadID.Value = data.threadID;
                        mailID.Value = data.mailID;
                        UserID.Value = data.UserID;
                        UserName.Value = data.UserName;
                        mailTime.Value = data.mailTime;
                        body.Value = data.body;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
                }
```

UPD: `MySqlBulkLoader` is not very suitable, since the data must be taken from a file, but for me it is taken from the server. But the main problem is that this data already contains `,`, `\r\n`, different characters and words in different languages, so it will be problematic to read them from the file and the format will be incorrect and errors will occur.

Comment: Use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`.

Comment: @RezaJaferi That's for MS SQL Server, not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an easy way to insert multiple rows try the `MySqlBulkLoader`. There is a good example in the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-bulk-loader.html). Or you could look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25323560/most-efficient-way-to-insert-rows-into-mysql-database) for example.

Comment: MySqlBulkLoader is not very suitable, since the data must be taken from a file, but for me it is taken from the server. But the main problem is that this data already contains `,` `\r\n`, different characters and words in different languages, so it will be problematic to read them from the file and the format will be incorrect and errors will occur.

Comment: @Gaben No, it won't be "problematic".

Comment: Please post a new question for that issue.

Comment: @Dai I tried to write data to cvs file. And as I said, the data was recorded, but loaded into the database incorrectly.

Comment: @Gaben "for me it is taken from the server". If the data is already in the MySQL Server, say, in a different table, take a look at the [`INSERT INTO ... SELECT` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html).

Comment: @Gaben You may also find [`MySqlBulkCopy`](https://mysqlconnector.net/api/mysqlconnector/mysqlbulkcopytype/) useful.

Comment: @Gaben perhaps you should use differenct `FieldTerminator` and `LineTerminator` if they clash with your content or try to use escape strings so your data won't break your "CSV" data. For more details read through the official documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-bulk-loader.html